# ngservice method called automatically and application stopped

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

my application have some dropdowns and one search button.after selection from dropdown click search button. It will display result based on selected values. I am using web api to fetch data from database. angular service will call those api methods

```
 //for family dropdown
this.getProresultByseriesFamily = function (family) {
    var res;
    if (family !== 0) {
        res = $http.get("/api/KendoCascading/GetProresult/" + family);
        return res;
    }
};
//for class dropdown
this.getFuseClassRes = function (fuseClass) {
    var res;
    if (fuseClass !== null) {
        res = $http.get("/api/KendoCascading/GetResFuse/" + fuseClass);
        return res;
    }
};
//for series dropdown
this.getresSeries = function (seID) {
    var res;
    if (seID !== 0) {
        res = $http.get("/api/KendoCascading/GetSeriesResult/" + seID);
        return res;
    }
};
```

**controller**

```
$scope.getProResult = function () {
    if ($scope.SelectedCriteria != null || $scope.SelectedCriteria!="") {
        var promise = ngservice.getProresultByseriesFamily($scope.SelectedCriteria);
        promise.then(function (resp) {
            console.log(resp.data);
            $scope.Products = resp.data;
            alert("successful1");
        }, function (err) {
            alert("Falied");
        });
    }
    if ($scope.FuseModel != null || $scope.FuseModel != "") {
        var promise = ngservice.getFuseClassRes($scope.FuseModel);
        promise.then(function (resp) {
            $scope.Products = resp.data;
            alert("successful2");
        }, function (err) {
            alert("failed");
        });
    }
  if ($scope.FuseSeriesModel != null || $scope.FuseSeriesModel != "") {
    var promise = ngservice.getresSeries($scope.FuseSeriesModel);
    promise.then(function (resp) {
        $scope.Products = resp.data;
        alert("successful");
    }, function (err) {
        alert("Failed");
    });
}
```

};

this controller function used as a click event in view. If i call first service method the view populate the result. But after some time it is automatically calling the 3rd service method and application stopped working. What is going wrong? if any better solution exist please help me.

api is working fine . i have checked in browser. It is fine.

**view**

```
<Button type="button" ID="Btn_Search" Width="90" Class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="getProResult();show=!show">Search</Button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is because sometimes your service returns `undefined`.

In the third case, which is the one with problem, if `$scope.FuseSeriesModel === 0`, `ngservice.getresSeries($scope.FuseSeriesModel)` will return `undefined` and it will throw an error because you are calling `then` on `undefined`.

I would recommend you to update your code to check for the promise before calling `.then`.

For example:

```
if ($scope.FuseSeriesModel != null || $scope.FuseSeriesModel != "") {
  var promise = ngservice.getresSeries($scope.FuseSeriesModel);
  if (promise) {
    promise.then(function (resp) {
      $scope.Products = resp.data;
      alert("successful");
    }, function (err) {
      alert("Failed");
    });
  }
}
```

Another way is to update your if conditions to `!!$scope.FuseSeriesModel` (or `Boolean($scope.FuseSeriesModel)`). That way, your promise code will be called only when the value is [Truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) which I think is what you really want to do:

```
if (Boolean($scope.FuseSeriesModel)) { // or $scope.FuseSeriesModel or !!$scope.FuseSeriesModel
  var promise = ngservice.getresSeries($scope.FuseSeriesModel);
  promise.then(function (resp) {
    $scope.Products = resp.data;
    alert("successful");
  }, function (err) {
    alert("Failed");
  }
);
```

Comment: Yes it works great. Thank a ton. Thanks for elaborate clarification

Comment: Hi muZk. i need one more help. when i passed two models together in different if condition **if((Boolean($scope.SelectedCriteria) && (Boolean($scope.FuseModel.FuseBodyType)))** like above for results. It is executing but after couple of secs it is executing single if condition of these two models. How to resist that. Please help me.

Comment: Hmm I don't understand what the problem is... but perhaps you have some problems with the if structure...

Comment: yes exactly. If i check condition for two models together. Then its executing fine but after some time its executing the single model also respectively. Like (if(boolean($scope.SelectedCriteria)&&(Boolean($scope.FuseModel)) together .It should give some particular set of result and It is giving the result. But after some time single if(Boolean($scope.SelectedCriteria) is executing and den if(Boolean($scope.FuseModel) too. How to resist that ? can you please just help me in if structure?

Comment: sure, can you share it? try to use gist.github.com